# How to make a '$N' within a string variable in a bash script be used as a operator in awk command when variable is expanded?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, operators, substitution

So due to the sugggestions Im gonna try be more conscise.

```
#!/bin/env bash

out1='$3 ~ "RB"'
out2='&& $3 ~ "F[0-9]"'
out3='&& $3 ~ /H*TF/'
printing=''"\t"'$3'

awk_output=$(awk -F, -v o1="$out1" -v o2="$out2" -v o3="$out3" -v p1="$printing" \
    'o1 o2 o3 { print NR,p1}' test.csv)


dialog --title "title" \
    --msgbox "$awk_output" 0 0
```

The above code is a example of a little program i am trying to write that takes a few user picked varibles, the outs and the printing variables at the top. And uses those to make a awk query of a database.

The problem is that the passed over variable strings contain a '$3' as an example. I want this to be read as a field operator in awk as it normally is but It is read as a literal string. Therefore when printing, awk prints the literal '$3' instead of the field it should represent in the csv file.
I have tried ENVIRON and SYMTAB with little success also. Has anyone come across this type of thing before as well?
Thank you, hope it was a bit more concise too.

jsut to clarify the output at the current moment is this:

```
1   $3
2   $3
3   $3
4   $3
5   $3
```

I would like the "$3" to actually represent a field of the csv file in the awk command. Something like this is what I am trying to get

```
1   "info from 3rd field in csv"
2   "info from 3rd field in csv"
3   "info from 3rd field in csv"
4   "info from 3rd field in csv"
5   "info from 3rd field in csv"
```

Comment: The subject line sounds like that'd be simple but there's SO much text to wade through to be sure I doubt if many people will have the time/enthusiasm to do so. Any way you can reduce all of that text and provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Honestly, I really tried, but it‘s so hard to understand even what the problem is.  If you could narrow it down a bit more and provide very specific problem description, that is just better to reach a wider community, than only the couple of guys trying to get into this.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate the suggestions and the time to reply and try have a look also :D 
Hope my edit is a bit easier to read if you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this to be read as a field operator in awk as it normally is but It is read as a literal string

So pass it as part of the command, not as a variable...

```
printing='$3'
awk -F, -v OFS='\t' "$out1 $out2 $out3 { print NR, $printing}" test.csv
```

Debug you shell scripts with `set -x`. Be sure to read about the difference between single and double quotes in shell and how the expansions happen.

Comment: Thankyou very much KamilCuk for the helkp and advice.

I didnt know you could use double quotes on the awk command as well, thought it was only single. Also thought I tried that also but I guess not. Thankyou very much again.

Will have a look at teh stuff you said as well.

Comment: Double and single quotes are parsed by _the shell_. Then _after_ the shell has parsed the expressions, _then_ `awk` is executed, and `awk` is a separate language with it's own quotes parsing rules.

Comment: ye that makes sense I guess. Thanks I will learn how this stuff works a bit better. Will do some reading on it. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is, rather than pass all the shell variables with special characters to `awk`, we can use `printf` to build the `awk` command and then use `eval` to execute and store the output.

**Modified Script:**

```
#!/bin/env bash

out1='$3 ~ "RB"'
out2='&& $3 ~ "F[0-9]"'
out3='&& $3 ~ /H*TF/'
printing='"\t"$3'

printf -v cmd $'awk -F, \'%s %s %s {print NR, %s}\'' "$out1" "$out2" "$out3" "$printing"
awk_output=$(eval "$cmd" test.csv)

dialog --title "title" \
   --msgbox "$awk_output" 0 0
```

**Explanation:**

- Changed `printing='"\t"$3'`. That is all is needed to print a tab in the output
- Included the printf line. `printf -v cmd $'awk -F, \'%s %s %s {print NR, %s}\'' "$out1" "$out2" "$out3" "$printing"`

  - variables will be substituited in `%s` placeholders
  - Note `$` in front of the `awk -F, ...`. This is because the awk string contains `'`. To use literal `'`, we need to add `$` before the string.

**CSV used:**

```
apple,orange,RBF1HTF
apple,orange,RBF2HTF
```

**Output:**

[image: result]

Comment: Thankyou Prasanna for the time to help with this. The answer from KamilCuk above was a bit less code and worked for me so I ended up using that way of doing it.

I learnt a few new commands from your code though so thank you for that. I really do appreciate it as I am very new to all this coding stuff and just doing some stuff that I need for my work. Thank you very much and have a good week.